# Quantos projetos eu posso ter no firebase?

Tags: firebase

Ola! Gostaria de saber se o Firebase tem um numero máximo de projetos que pode ser criado e gerenciado? Obg por ler a pergunta!

Comment: [Nessa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38120044/cannot-create-new-project-in-firebase-console), do stackoverflow en, é mensionado um máximo de 10 projetos gratuitos

Answer (score 1):

Veja o comentário do Frank [nesta questão](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38120044/5861618). Frank é um dos Engenheiros do Firebase. Ele diz:

> There's no limit on the number of projects in general, but there is a
>   limit on the number of projects on an unpaid plan. The exact limit for
>   that varies, from what I understand.

Traduzindo:

> Não há um limite no número de projetos em geral, mas há um limite de
>   projectos gratuitos. O limite exacto pode variar, que eu saiba.